# Acoustic sound box simulator

Tags: acoustics, simulations

I'm looking for a simulator (2 or 3 dimensional + time) of an acoustic box.

I'm trying to see where the high/low pressure areas would be depending on where I tap the box on the outside.

PS. Not sure if the question makes complete sense

Comment: I'm just not sure it's on-topic - it seems more like a software request than a question about acoustics

Comment: Indeed it is a software request, but who better to know than the physicists themselves?

Comment: This kind of request clearly belongs into engineering. Physicists don't care about this kind of problem unless they have taken a job in a company that solves acoustic problems as part of its business, in which case they are basically acoustics engineers. Just to give you a hint, though, the problem is NOT easy.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question in a way. I need a computationally efficient method, and clearly this would not be the way to go.